# Lottie file animation play when selected (Expo)

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, expo, lottie

I want it to play only when the card is selected, if the card is not selected it simply displays the lottie file but nothing is being played. Right now I get an error of `cannot read property 'play' of null`. When I remove the `animationPress()` and get the file to run it also start at the mentioned `initialSegment` that I'm passing into it.

What am I doing wrong here?

My card that the Lottie file is in:

```
   const animation = useRef(null);

    const animationPress = () => {
        animation.current.play();
    }

return(
{filteredData.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSelected(item), animationPress()}>
                                        <View style={[{ alignItems: 'center' }, selected.id == item.id ? { paddingTop: 10 } : { paddingTop: 20 }]}>
                                            <CardioCard style={selected.id == item.id ? { backgroundColor: 'green', fontFamily: 'ssb_SemiBold' } : {}} >
                                                <CardItem style={[styles.card, selected.id == item.id ? { backgroundColor: 'green' } : {}]}>
                                                    <Text>

                                                        < LottieView
                                                            ref={animation}
                                                            source={require('../../assets/images/heartbeat.json')}
                                                            initialSegment={68,135}
                                                            autoPlay={true}
                                                            loop={true}
                                                            style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
                                              
                                                    </Text>
                                                </CardItem>
                                            </CardioCard>
                                            <Text style={[{ fontSize: 18, color: 'hsl(98, 0%, 11%)', paddingLeft: 15 }, selected.id == item.id ? { fontFamily: 'ssb_SemiBold' } : {}]}>{item.name}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </>
                            )
                        })}
...
)
```

**Edit**
I also tried to do `useState` for the `autoplay` and `loop` button so they would be false but when the button is pressed it would turn `true` but the animation wouldn't load even after the button press.

```
    const [playAnimation, setPlayAnimation] = useState(false);

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setPlayAnimation(true)}>

    <LottieView
        source={require('../../assets/images/heartbeat.json')}
        autoPlay={playAnimation}
        loop={playAnimation}
        style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
    /> 
</TouchableOpacity>
```

this is driving me nuts and idk what to do anymore.

Comment: you can try to provide the duration prop to the LottieView when an item selected as you are using it for styling your component.

Comment: but duration plays the speed. You are saying tell it that if it's not selected have a duration of zero and then if it's selected have a duration of what the animation runs at?

Comment: Try to provide duration with the condition in duration prop 1000 when selected otherwise 0

Comment: I added this and nothing changed. It continues to play and loop through the animation: 
`style={[styles.animationSize, selected.id == item.id ? { duration: 5600 } : { duration: 0 } ]} `

Comment: not like this, here you have provided duration prop in style props

provide duration prop in LottieView Component like as below

<LottieView
    ref={animation}
    source={require('../../assets/images/heartbeat.json')}
    initialSegment={68,135}
    autoPlay={true}
    loop={true}
duration={selected.id == item.id ? 1000 : 0 }
    style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />

Comment: Oh my apologies. So I just tried this and the other cards still continued looping through the animation.

Comment: Try to wrap the component in separate component and also try to use the internal state to set selected instead in the render item function of the flatlist

Comment: Could you expand on this? I also updated my question and idk if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to react-native but I guess it's like react. Not sure to correctly understand the issue.

In this case, shouldn't you use `animation.current` instead of `animation` as your lottieView ref? or at least ensure that your ref `animation` is defined (not null) so that the container can be mounted even if not launched, this is also for your `animationPress`  function. Also you should disable the `autoPlay` I guess (since you want to trigger the animation with a button).

```
< LottieView
         ref={animation.current}
         source={require('../../assets/images/heartbeat.json')}
         initialSegment={68,135}
         autoPlay={false}
         loop={true}
         style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
```

or

```
{animation && < LottieView
         ref={animation}
         source={require('../../assets/images/heartbeat.json')}
         initialSegment={68,135}
         autoPlay={false}
         loop={true}
         style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />}
```

And of course

```
   const animationPress = () => {
     if(animation?.current) {
        animation.current.play();
     }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to type this out. Sadly it didn't render any of the animations. I'm also new to react native and it already seems like you have a way better grasp of it than I do though lol

Comment: Try to change the ref as I suggested, because `ref` is a mutable object that contains a `current` which points on the "real" container. So I'm feeling like you shouldn't use the ref like that.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a little confused. Could explain that a little more. I tried to `ref={animation.current}` but it didn't load the file. What should I set my `useRef`too if not `null`. I'm confused on what to actually set it too

Comment: When your component is mounted, useRef will change from `null` to a mutable object containing `current`. So it's ok to initialize it to null but you have to ensure that the ref has been placed before using it. If not, you will have an error.
I don't know what lib you are using for react-native, but make sure what kind of state of the ref is required. Is it a reference to an Element in this case, you should place your ref on an Element and the pass `ref.current` to your component? or does this LottieView is itself the container and in this case it just needd the `ref` ?